# Pygrass ERROR: Mapset is not set

Tags: python, grass-gis

I am using Pygrass in a a Python Grass GIS stand alone application.
I am using GRASS GIS 7.0.3 on a Windows machine and Python 2.7.4.
I am initializing a new Grass environment. I can work in this environment, and apply grass functions (e.g. load shapefiles,...)

I would like to access the Vector data directly using this example:

```
from pygrass.vector import VectTopo
municip = VectTopo('boundary_municp_sqlite')
municip.is_open()
False
municip.mapset
''
municip.exist()  # check if exist, and if True set mapset
True
municip.mapset
'user1'
```

Unfortunately I get the following Error during the command municip.exist():

```
ERROR: MAPSET is not set
```

But I can work in the environment, the variables Location and Mapset("PERMANENT") are set. I also used g.region to set the region.
I tried to use the module from grass.pygrass.gis import Mapset.
This also gives me an error when I try to access the function:

```
from grass.pygrass.gis import Mapset
m = Mapset()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-73310da5f35b> in <module>()
----> 1 m = Mapset()

C:\Program Files (x86)\GRASS GIS 7.0.3\etc\python\grass\pygrass\gis\__init__.py
in __init__(self, mapset, location, gisdbase)
    265         self.gisdbase = gisdbase
    266         self.location = location
--> 267         self.name = mapset
    268         self.visible = VisibleMapset(self.name, self.location, self.gisd
base)
    269

C:\Program Files (x86)\GRASS GIS 7.0.3\etc\python\grass\pygrass\gis\__init__.py
in _set_name(self, name)
    290
    291     def _set_name(self, name):
--> 292         self._name = _check(name, join(self._gisdb, self._loc), "MAPSET"
)
    293
    294     name = property(fget=_get_name, fset=_set_name,

C:\PROGRA~2\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\ntpath.pyc in join(a, *p)
     71             b_wins = 1
     72
---> 73         elif isabs(b):
     74             # This probably wipes out path so far.  However, it's more
     75             # complicated if path begins with a drive letter:

C:\PROGRA~2\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\ntpath.pyc in isabs(s)
     55 def isabs(s):
     56     """Test whether a path is absolute"""
---> 57     s = splitdrive(s)[1]
     58     return s != '' and s[:1] in '/\\'
     59

C:\PROGRA~2\QGISPI~1\apps\Python27\lib\ntpath.pyc in splitdrive(p)
    123     """Split a pathname into drive and path specifiers. Returns a 2-tupl
e
    124 "(drive,path)";  either part may be empty"""
--> 125     if p[1:2] == ':':
    126         return p[0:2], p[2:]
    127     return '', p

TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am not sure if both errors are connected somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem on Mac OS X or Linux (GRASS 7.0.3 and GRASS 7.1)

```
from grass.pygrass.gis import Mapset
m = Mapset()
m
Mapset('Hamoir')
print m
Hamoir
m.glist('vector')
['axes_plis', 'barre_giv_lignes', 'failles_hamoir', 'hydro']
from grass.pygrass.vector import VectorTopo
axes = VectorTopo('axes_plis')
axes.exist()
True
axes.mapset
'Hamoir'
```

It may be a problem of the path of your gisdb. The error is in the file [ntpath.py](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/ntpath.py) (specific to Windows = common operations on Windows pathnames), line 125 because p is empty.

```
    123     """Split a pathname into drive and path specifiers. Returns a 2-tuple
    124 "(drive,path)";  either part may be empty"""
--> 125     if p[1:2] == ':':
    126         return p[0:2], p[2:]
    127     return '', p

   TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Thanks for testing it, i think you were right with the comments. I opened an existing location in the GUI and printed all environmental variables, and added them to my PATH in the standalone script. Now it works fine!